# Detecting Intersections of a Ray with a Polygon

Tags: image-processing, geometry, image-analysis

As a part of a math essay, I am writing a program that detects intersections of a line that is drawn with a shape that is inputted.

For example, in the shape below, The polygon is the input image of a given size. The ray has been drawn onto the polygon starting from within the polygon. How can I detect the number of times the ray crosses the boundary of the polygon.

Also, the polygon is always a closed polygon.

[image]

A thought that originally came to my mind was to fill the polygon with the same colour as the border (black). And then count the number of times a ray would meet black followed by white.

My problem with this method is that I don't really know how to trace along a line and check each point and I'm guessing that it would be an extremely expensive process to continuously check along the line.

I'm using Processing 3 right now but I'm okay to use any other software/platform except MatLab because I don't have access to it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the polygon border is black on a white image you may do as following:

1. Draw a Line
   Draw a line from its starting point to the end of the image.
   You should use white color for the line.
   You may find [Draw a line using an angle and a point in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252438) useful.
2. Apply `XOR` Operation
   Assume the input image is Boolean (1 for all data, zero for polygon) and also the output of (1) (Where the line is making some of the polygon white) you may do `xor` between them.
3. Count the 1
   To count the number of intersections you only need to count the number of `1` in the output of the `xor` operation.

In case you have several non overlapping polygons in the image you may extract them one by one and apply this on each.

**Remark**: As noted by @[CrisLuengo](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/33605/cris-luengo), in practice one needs to take care of shallow angles. To address that, one of the solutions is working on connected components and not individual pixels.

Comment: If the line has a small angle with an edge of the polygon, the two will have multiple pixels in common, indicating a single intersection. Maybe count connected components instead of individual pixels?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I agree. I sketched the idea, in practice you're right.